# In IntelliJ IDEA, can I switch branches in the middle of resolving merge conflicts and resume it later where I left off?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am going through many files in IntelliJ to resolve merge conflicts. I have to perform another task on a different branch, but whenever I go to checkout the branch it says I need to resolve merge conflicts on the current branch first. This is a very large project I am syncing multiple branches together. I have already gone through many files and have many more to go. I do not want to accept all of one branches changes, and I don't want to abort the merge because then I would have to restart when I come back. Is there a way I can pause/stash resolving merge conflicts and then come back?

I have tried to `git stash push -m "merge"` but it says the files "need merge" and the changes don't get stashed. I have also just tried to checkout a different branch and it says I can't checkout.

Comment: I think checking out another branch will probably lose the changes you made for resolving the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Directly in intelliJ? Probably not.

You could however do it by using `git worktree`

`git worktree` basically makes another checkout of the repository in another directory.

From the root of your git repository try the following (in git bash).
`git worktree add ../checkout2 <some-commit-or-branch>`
This will create the checkout in the folder "checkout2" with a branch called "checkout2" starting from the given commit or branch.

To remove the worktree again use `git worktree remove ../checkout2`